# HMACSHA1 gives different output between JS and VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, hmac, hmacsha1

I'm trying to translate a JavaScript application of TOTP to VB.Net: http://blog.tinisles.com/2011/10/google-authenticator-one-time-password-algorithm-in-javascript/

I have encountered a problem during translation of the HMAC-part:

```
//Javascript:
var hmacObj = new jsSHA("Hello World!", 'HEX');
var hmac = hmacObj.getHMAC("secret", 'HEX', 'SHA-1', "HEX");
```

This is a codesnippet of my translation in VB.Net

```
'VB.Net:
Dim hmacObjTest As New HMACSHA1(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret"))
Dim hmacTest As Byte() = hmacObjTest.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!"))
Dim hmacHexTest As New StringBuilder()

    For i As Integer = 0 To hmacTest.Length - 1
        hmacHexTest.Append(hmacTest(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next i

Dim strTest As String = "HMAC = " & hmacHexTest.ToString()
```

The problem is that i get different output from the two languages:

```
Output JS: 5efed98b0787c83f9cb0135ba283c390ca49320e //Tested from jsSha demo: http://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/
Output VB.Net: 87b0154b8420c0b58869ca103f481e824d8876ea
```

The outputs are not at all the same like they are in this question: [hmacsha1 output hex strings different between vb.net and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615322/hmacsha1-output-hex-strings-different-between-vb-net-and-python)

Does anyone know where I might be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hashes don't work on strings - they work on the binary representation of the string. Now you use UTF-8 as encoding for the dotnet version, while the JavaScript version is very likely not to use UTF-8 - so you get different binary representations, resulting in different hashes.

Use either [webttolkit](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html) or the hackish `var utfstring = unescape(encodeURIComponent(rawstring));` to convert to UTF-8 before calcualting the hash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The JavaScript code has the output i am looking for, so i don't need to change the code for that. Do you know the encoding standard that's used in JavaScript's getHMAC? Any way to change to the right standard in VB.Net instead?

Comment: The encoding used is defined by `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`, in this case obviously UTF-8. You can use the encoding of your choice here.